# Proof that a non-zero vector b is a 1- eigenvector of an idempotent matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\vec{b}$ is a nonzero vector in the image of an idempotent matrix A. Prove that b is a 1-eigenvector of A. Use this to argue that the 1-eigenspace of A is precisely im(A). I've thought about this for quite some time but I'm stuck as to how to approach this proof. Any help is appreciated.

Following Steven's suggestion, I know that:
$$
A\vec{v}=\vec{b}\ne\vec{0}
$$
for some $\vec{v}$. And I would use the fact that $A=A^{2}$ to show that $\vec{b}$ is in the $\ker(A-(1)I_{n})$, meaning that it is in $E_{1}$.

Comment: So $b=Av\ne0$, then $(A-I)b=(A-I)Av=0$ becasue $A^2=A\Leftrightarrow(A-I)A=0$

Comment: It would be helpful if you added your thoughts on this question, in particular the results you know, or similar problems you have done regarding eigenvectors. Posting the exact source of the question will be helpful as well, for the sake of context. I request you to edit your post with these details so that the question improves and is more attractive for future visitors and/or answerers? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $b=Av\ne0$, thus $(A-I)b=(A-I)Av=0$ becasue $A^2=A\Leftrightarrow(A-I)A=0$. This basically shows that $\text{Im}(A)\subseteq E_1$, the eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue $1$. Now to show $E_1\subseteq \text{Im}(A)$, suppose $v\ne0$ is an eigenvector so that $Av=v$. Doesn't this equation itself tell you that $v\in\text{Im}(A)$ as $v$ is its own image?

Answer (score 1):

When approaching a proof like this, it helps to start by writing out what we know in a more concrete form. If $\vec{b}$ is in the image of $A,$ then there exists some vector $\vec{x}$ in the preimage of $A$ such that $A\vec{x} = \vec{b},$ and if $A$ is idempotent, then $AA = A.$

Because $AA = A,$ we must have that $(AA)\vec{x} = A\vec{x}.$ Because matrix multiplication is associative, we must have that $(AA)\vec{x} = A(A\vec{x}),$ so $A(A\vec{x}) = A\vec{x}.$ Now substituting in our definition of $\vec{b}$ gives us that $A\vec{b} = \vec{b},$ which is the definition of an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1.$

Comment: Stephen. Your answer is very helpful. Specifically, your suggestion about writing out what we know in a more concrete form is a great approach. Unfortunately, my low reputation prevents me from giving you an upvote. But I want to let you know that your answer is well received and much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm glad I could be of service

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$ker(I-A)= Im(A).$$

Proof:

1. if $x \in ker(I-A)$, then $Ax=x$, hence $x \in Im(A).$
2. if $x \in Im(A),$ then $x=Ay$ for some $y$, hence $x=Ay=A^2y=A(Ay)=Ax,$ thus $x \in ker(I-A).$